# Custom type spanning as many columns as it has fields in a DML statement

Tags: oracle, function, select, types, plsql

Say I have a custom datatype that has a number of members. For example:

```
create type myType as object(
  field1  number,
  field2  varchar2(50),
  field3  varchar2(25)
);
```

Now if I have a function that returns `myType` and put it in, say, a `select` statement, Oracle will return something like:

```
select myTypeFunction() from dual;

> myTypeFunction()
> -------------------------------------------------
> schemaowner.myType(1,'something','another thing')
```

Is there a generic way that I can span those three (in this example) fields into their own columns; so, in this case, I would like to have returned:

```
> field1  field2     field3
> --------------------------------
>      1  something  another thing
```

I know it's possible by calling the function multiple times. For example:

```
select myTypeFunction().field1,
       myTypeFunction().field2,
       myTypeFunction().field3
from   dual;
```

Or, by calling the function once in a subquery (or, similarly, using a table type):

```
select x.y.field1, x.y.field2, x.y.field3
from   (select myTypeFunction() y from dual) x;

-- or, where myTypeFunction has been modified to return a table of myType:

select field1,field2,field3 from table(myTypeFunction());
```

However, all these ways seem messy and inefficient -- with the last option perhaps looking the most attractive, barring alternatives -- so I would prefer to avoid doing them, if possible. Moreover, I believe that none of these ways would work if the function had parameters that were fed values from elsewhere; for example:

```
select x.field1, x.field2, x.field3
from   lookupTable alpha,
       table(anotherTypeFunction(alpha.id)) x;
```

or a more complicated join, where `anotherTypeFunction` obviously returns different values based upon its parameter(s). (Although I'm not very sure about this!)

Thanks :)

Comment: If you think there is a performance problem, you could let us understand what this performance problem is. To do this, would you be so kind to submit: 1) Oracle version - 2)Sample data - 3)Function code- 4) If your function accesses data in db, provide the table definition and indexes 5) The output expected - 6) Performance(number of operations expected, and the operations done in a unit of time).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for as you very much list the alternatives and then refuse to use any of them without solid argumentation. I don't think any of them is messy (a matter of personal opinion) or inefficient (I don't have any profiling to prove that either).

There should be no problems to pass parameters to `myTypeFunction` and `anotherTypeFunction` in your examples.

This example will give you the output you were asking. `myTypeToTable` is independent of members of `myType`.

```
create or replace type myType as object(
  field1 number,
  field2 varchar2(20),
  field3 varchar2(20)
);
/

create or replace type myTypeList as table of myType;
/

create or replace function myTypeToTable(obj in myType)
return myTypeList pipelined as
begin
  pipe row(obj);
  return;
end;
/

select * from table(myTypeToTable(myType(34, 'foo', 'and more foo')));

    FIELD1 FIELD2               FIELD3
---------- -------------------- --------------------
    34     foo                  and more foo
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

What I am looking for is something like `select SomeOracleFunction(myType(34,'foo','bar')) from dual;` to do the trick. The reason I ask is because, in my first example, I would end up calling the same function three times -- which is definitely inefficient, unless Oracle is clever enough to cache the results -- and in the second and third examples, I can't (I presume) feed parameters values from other table fields. If I'm wrong about that, then there's no problem; I will test now Oracle is in front of me!!

Comment: ...OK, the parameters things does work -- but it's _so_ slow!

Comment: @Christopher Harrison: AFAIK I'm afraid you're asking too much. You can't get the syntax you are looking for but you have to use `select ... from table(...);`. I might be wrong though as I'm an Oracle newbie. Unfortunately I have no idea of the performance of this solution and I'm also interested in to hear a second opinion(s).